# Improving Python Exponential smoothing

Tags: time-series, python, exponential-smoothing

I am going to improve my code to the Exponential smoothing I submitted to Statsmodel which can be found [here](https://github.com/ccsv/statsmodels/blob/85b6421ff54bbda179e4331e2dc22b3169795b23/statsmodels/tsa/_expsmoothing). The code handles 15 different variation Standard Exponential Smoothing models including Holt-Winters, SES, Brown, Holt, and Damped models.

I have several questions what are State Space Models and Error correction forms? I do not really understand them.

Secondly how do I solve for the hyperparameters and the damped parameters? is there a good way to fit them?

Third there are `for` loops I am trying to eliminate to reduce the speed. How do I do this?

Also I want suggestions for summary and other features that can be easily added.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts contributing to open source software. I think you need to reform this question... The first two questions should become separate posts. The third question is probably better left to stackoverflow or the statsmodels mailing group. Finally, I think you can answer the fourth question by looking at MATLAB, R and other software for state space modeling. For example I just did an internet search for "<language> state space model kalman smoothing" with R and MATLAB as <language> and found a number of papers and software implementations.

Comment: @JoshHermann For the third point see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919719/python-numpy-iteration-improvements-for-exponential-smoothing-working-code-for